# Changing table column name when build Laravel web API

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem to build a web API with Laravel. When I fetch data from query its return data with table actual name. suppose if I return user table data its look like these.

```
{
  ["first_name":"John", "last_name":"Doe"],
  ["first_name":"Abdul", "last_name":"Karim"]
}
```

But I want to changing table actual column name, so its look like

```
{
  ["f_name":"John", "l_name":"Doe"],
  ["f_name":"Abdul", "l_name":"Karim"]
}
```

How can I do it from Laravel eloquent ORM?

Comment: Out of curiosity: why in the name of rasmus lerdorf do you want to do that?   The first one is more readable, makes more sense, and is more common in an API. The second one looks like someone trying to save 8 bytes per record for no real, defined reason at the expense of code complexity (which *never* pays off).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this in your model,by using **Laravel Accessors & Mutators**
for more follow this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators here i give you a sample code as per your requirement

```
class Channel extends Eloquent {

public function getFNameAttribute()
{
    return $this->attributes['first_name'];
}

}
```